# LibreOffice Menus appear in poor contrast

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

Ubuntu 16.04 / x64 
Libreoffice 5.1.4.2

I have no hint as to why this is happening (see the following image):

[image]

All the titles of the "Tabs" appear in white, and therefore I cannot see anything. This is happening on multiple computers with the same installations. This is also happening in other tabs as well (e.g. Paragraph settings etc.)

What should be done to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is known, look here :

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92776

to be continued ...